# Need to check if any one of two keys are there in object javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I am trying to check if any one of the two given keys are available in a given object

```
let keys = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

given object

```
let obj = {
  "foo": "value"
}

let obj1 = {
  "key": "value"
}
```

As we can see in obj `foo` is present and in `obj1` none of the given keys are present.

```
"key" in obj //can check for single key like this
```

Need to check anyone of given key should be present in object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to iterate over the `keys` list and [`Object#hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check if the object has a key:

```js
const hasKeyInList = (obj = {}, keys = []) =>
  keys.some(key => obj.hasOwnProperty(key));

const keys = ['foo', 'bar'];
console.log( hasKeyInList({"foo": "value"}, keys) );
console.log( hasKeyInList({"key": "value"}, keys) );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) combined with [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
let obj = {
  foo: 'value',
  key: 'value'
}

let keys = ['foo', 'bar']

// true
console.log(Object.keys(obj).some(k => keys.includes(k)));

keys = ['bar','bar'];
// false
console.log(Object.keys(obj).some(k => keys.includes(k)));
```